# Error when I am trying to execute show version into a Cisco device

Tags: ansible, network-programming, cisco

I am trying to learn Ansible but I have some problems: I did a simple playbook, my first one, but it didn't work well: I am able to connect to my device with  user `teste` and password `teste` and also execute the command.

> fatal: [ansible_user=teste]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
> "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 10 secs.\nSee the timeout
> setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."}
> fatal: [ansible_password=teste]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
> "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 10 secs.\nSee the timeout
> setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."}
> fatal: [192.168.0.103]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "command
> timeout triggered, timeout value is 10 secs.\nSee the timeout setting
> options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."}

This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: First Play
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: False
  connection:  local
  tasks:
   - name: Fist Task
     ios_command:
         commands: show version
     register: version
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run your playbook with `-vvv` to see if you could get some more valuable info ?

Comment: thanks for the tip. is my user  and password ?

<ansible_password=teste> using connection plugin network_cli (was local)
fatal: [ansible_user=teste]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 10 secs.\nSee the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."
}
fatal: [192.168.0.103]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 10 secs.\nSee the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."
}

Answer (score 1):

well, I have to change my host file:

this way did not work:

```
[routers]
192.168.0.103
ansible_user=teste
ansible_password=teste
```

after  check in the internet, I tried this way and worked fine:

```
[routers]
192.168.0.103


[routers:vars]
ansible_user=teste
ansible_password=teste
ansible_connection=network_cli
ansible_network_os=ios
```

Answer (score 0):

The was issue was resolved after adding the username and password in the hosts file